# SqlAlchemy with relationship query seems to delay populating child nested property

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

when I run the following query the 'values' attribute appears to load when I step over in debugging, but appears to be 'None' when I run it normally:

```
first = self._data_manager.session \
            .query(Brand) \
            .filter(Brand.auth_user_id == auth_user_id) \
            .first()
```

(I have used classical a mapping approach) the models are defined as:

```
@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Brand(DataModel):
    brand_name: str = None
    brand_description: str = None
    website: str = None
    logo: str = None
    header_image: str = None
    insta_handle: str = None
    values: list[Value] = field(default_factory=list)

@dataclass(unsafe_hash=True)
class Value(DataModel):
    value: ValueEnum = None
```

The SQLAlchemy relationship mapping is configured as following:

```
sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Brand, brand_table, properties={
            'values': orm.relationship(Value,
                                       foreign_keys=value_table.c.entity_id,
                                       primaryjoin=brand_table.c.id == value_table.c.entity_id,
                                       overlaps="values")
        })
sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Value, value_table)
```

My SQLAlchemy tables are defined

```
value_table = Table('value', Base.metadata,
                    Column('id', String(length=36), primary_key=True),
                    Column('created', DateTime),
                    Column('value', Enum(ValueEnum)),
                    Column('entity_id', String(length=64)))

brand_table = Table('brand', Base.metadata,
                    Column('id', String(length=36), primary_key=True),
                    Column('created', DateTime),
                    Column('auth_user_id', String(length=64)),
                    Column('brand_name', String(length=120)),
                    Column('brand_description', String(length=500)),
                    Column('header_image', String(length=360)),
                    Column('categories', PickleType),
                    Column('insta_handle', String(length=30)),
                    Column('website', String(length=120)),
                    Column('logo', String(length=360)))
```

Comment: By default relationships are lazy-loaded, so they are empty until the attribute is explicitly accessed.  See also [Eager Loading](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/tutorial.html#eager-loading).

Comment: thanks @snakecharmerb, I figured this out soon after the post after I turned on echo=True in the engine and noticed two seperate select statements rather than a join